# изменение в styleSheet

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Как изменить в QPushButton только 1 элемент на styleSheet? Если сделать так:

```
setStyleSheet("QPushButton {"
                  "background-color: blue;"
                  "}");
```

то остальние елементи(border-radius, ... ) стают по дефолту. А нужно изменить только 1 елемент, остальние не трогать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стили для отдельных элементов управления указываются через спецификатор вида `класс#имя`. Имена же самих элементов задаются с помощью метода `setObjectName`.

Пример окрашивания текста кнопки с именем *myButtonName* в красный цвет:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setApplicationName("Sample Application");

    // Задаём стиль для кнопки с именем myButtonName.
    qApp->setStyleSheet("QPushButton#myButtonName{color:red}");

    // Кнопка с именем, указанным в стилях. Стили применяются.
    QPushButton button1;
    button1.setObjectName("myButtonName");
    button1.setText("Red Button");
    button1.show();

    // Кнопка с именем, не указанным в стилях. Стили НЕ применяются.
    QPushButton button2;
    button2.setObjectName("anotherButton");
    button2.setText("Another Named Button");
    button2.show();

    // Кнопка без имени. Стили также НЕ применяются.
    QPushButton button3;
    button3.setText("Unnamed Button");
    button3.show();

    button1.show();
    button2.show();
    button3.show();
    return qApp->exec();
}
```