# Фоновая картинка QT c++

Tags: c++, qt

Как изменить фоновую картинку в QT в определенной форме? 
Если  юзаю в Stylesheet:

```
background-image: url(:/images/images/fon.jpg);
```

Меняется сразу во всех.

Comment: Вам надо в стилях указать `objectName()`‐имя формы по типу `QWidget#имя-формы {background-image: ...}`. Пример можно посмотреть в моём ответе на похожий вопрос «[Изменение в styleSheet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511789/208074)».